# Why my bot has no permissions to assign roles?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create this command for my bot assign high roles such as ADM based on their money but even with the administrator permission on the API its still giving me the same error, what am i doing wrong?

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name='+$50.000')
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

The error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj0EY.png

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are adding the role Admin which typically is one of the highest roles, just be sure that the bot has higher permissions than the Admin role so it can grant the role.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`MissingPermission` error is not related to the bot's itself. It related to user. So be sure that also the user of the command has `manage roles` permission. But just in case be sure also the bot has the same permission when you add it to the server. If you still have a problem, just comment

Comment: even with permission, its weird ( https://i.imgur.com/Vk2ayqP.png )

Comment: Try to kick the bot, then reinvite it to your server with administrator then if you are sure that you have `manage roles` permission, it must be work.